# Run your own python script in background

Tags: linux, unix, python, monit

I have my own python library which gets installed wide when I do this

```
python setup.py install
```

inside python project directory, it copies the executable file in bin also, but basically I am doing all this so, that it can be run as a service and I should be able to include it in upstart or monit kind of unix libraries. My process name is `watchman` when I do this `watchman &` to make it daemon its not exactly making it daemon. Am I doing something wrong in making it daemon. I am beginner in this can anyone really help me in this.

Comment: `&` doesn't daemonize a process; that only moves it into the background.  A background process and a daemon are considerably different, given that the expectation of a daemon is to have a thread which can't be killed by exiting the terminal session.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is used to run a process in the background. It's still very much attached to the terminal (`tty`) you run it from.

These are the basic steps to making a process a daemon:

1. Fork your process and kill its parent so that it becomes an orphan (handled directly by `init`)
2. Detach it from its current process group by assigning a new session using `setsid()`
3. *Now* `exec` your daemon process
4. Fork it again so that it gets detached from the terminal you ran it from
5. Now reload the file descriptors (since it lost them while getting detached from the terminal) such as `stdin`, `stdout`.